# Condition to Continue a For Loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, if-statement

First go around with programming in VB.net and came across a little issue. I'm trying to find a way to have an `If` statement control whether a `for` loop executes or not before going through another iteration.

Code:

```
    For Each theTable In tableDoc.Tables
        testString = ""
        For row = 1 To theTable.Rows.Count
            isHeaderOrNot = theTable.Cell(row, 1).Range.Text 'Gets value in first column
            If isHeaderOrNot is Not Like "Section" or "Field" then Continue For 'if the words "Section" or "Field" are NOT included in isHeaderOrNot then continue with For loop
            keyText = theTable.Cell(row, 2).Range.Text
            valueText = theTable.Cell(row, 3).Range.Text
            Console.WriteLine("KEY: {0}", keyText)
            Console.WriteLine("VALUE: {0}", valueText)
            Console.WriteLine("")
        Next
    Next
```

I'm getting an error on `Like` saying there's an expression expected..

Basically if the first column in the row the for loop is in contains Section or Field I want it go to the next line. First time trying to explain a question dealing with this, so any questions just ask! I truly appreciate your time!

Comment: You need: `If isHeaderOrNot is Not Like "Section" and isHeaderOrNot is Not Like "Field"`  (note the `and` not `or` to exclude both) - may as well use `<>` rather than `like` as you have no wildcards.

Comment: Good suggestion and thanks for your time!, but I'm still receiving an error on the first "Like" in your code. @AlexK.

Comment: What is this thing? Excel? `theTable.Cell(row, 1)` datatables dont have cells

Comment: Why do you need to use the LIKE operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just include the whole block in the `if`, and if it's not the case and you want to end the loop, you can use `Exit For`.

```
For Each theTable In tableDoc.Tables
    testString = ""
    For row = 1 To theTable.Rows.Count
        isHeaderOrNot = theTable.Cell(row, 1).Range.Text

        'If cell doesn't contain Section or Field, then do the following
        If Not isHeaderOrNot.contains("Section") AndAlso Not isHeaderOrNot.contains("Field")
            keyText = theTable.Cell(row, 2).Range.Text
            valueText = theTable.Cell(row, 3).Range.Text
            Console.WriteLine("KEY: {0}", keyText)
            Console.WriteLine("VALUE: {0}", valueText)
            Console.WriteLine("")
        Else

            'If it DOES include Section or Field, then stop looping
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax should be

```
If Not isHeaderOrNot Like "Section" AndAlso 
   Not isHeaderOrNot Like "Field" Then 
   Exit For
```